# Django's runserver on Oracle Cloud?

Tags: django, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am trying to use a free instance of Oracle Cloud for my Django project.
But I have no idea how I can check the Django's "runserver" page like this

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

since the public IP address given to my instance didn't load the Django's page.

I tried to look into "network" session of Oracle Cloud but I wasn't able to find any meaningful stuff
related to this.
When I googled this, it seemed that it has to do with firewall setting in terms of Google Cloud so maybe Oracle has the same but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain if you're familiar with this document but it should assist with creating Python applications with Django with Oracle in mind, as well as troubleshooting - https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/python/python-django-accs/python-django-accs.html